# Show page message and reload page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, pagemessages

I have a VF page and extensions for it where I perform update operation. If it is successful or not I want to display page message - on VF I have

```
 <apex:pageMessages />
```

and in Apex controller I have

```
 ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Update successful'));
```

However, when I click button which invoke my update operation I need to perform as well page refreshing. So I have

```
    oncomplete="location.reload();"
```

on my button. This causes that I cannot see my page messages since the page is refreshed immediately. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: some more code

```
    public PageReference update() {
       // my logic
         try {
             update myMap.values();
             ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Update successful'));
             return null;
         } catch(DmlException ex) {
             ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new     ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, ex.getDmlMessage(0));
             ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
             return null;
          }
    }



    <apex:page standardController="MyObject__c" extensions="MyController" standardStylesheets="true" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0">

     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS214, '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css')}" />

     <div class="slds">
         <apex:pageMessages />
         //...
         <button onclick="callUpdate(); return false;" class="slds-button slds-button--brand"> Save </button>
        <apex:actionFunction name="UpdateAction" action="{!update}" reRender="panel" oncomplete="setTimeout(location.reload(),5000)" />
     </div>

      <script>

        function callUpdate() {
            UpdateAction();
       }
       </script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `PageReference` navigation instead? Then you can have your action return `null` in the error case and have it not redirect.

Comment: Returning null from the action that the button invokes will re-display the page including the message you added.

Comment: Ok, my action return null PageReference but it does not refresh the content of my page.

Comment: Does the button specify a `reRender` Id so that only part of the page updates? Remove that.

Comment: No it doesn't. I added more code in first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of reloading immediately, you could set a timeout:

```
oncomplete="setTimeout(function() { location.reload() },1000)"
```

Feel free to adjust the 1000 value to whatever you like (1000 is 1 second).

You could also have this be an actionFunction that simply reRenders, which would clear the message:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="refresh" reRender="form" />

... oncomplete="setTimeout(refresh, 1000)" />
```

---

As for why your messages are not appearing:

It seems that you're reRendering a part of the page that does not include the apex:pageMessages. They're not rendered because the element wasn't targeted for rerendering.

```
<apex:pageMessages id="messages" />

...

    <apex:actionFunction name="UpdateAction" action="{!update}" reRender="panel,messages"
     oncomplete="setTimeout(function() { location.reload() }, 5000)" />
```

Comment: In this case my page messages are not displayed

Comment: @rmatusiak Then you're doing something else wrong. We don't have enough code to know what's wrong...

Comment: I put some more code. I have to use button instead of apex:commandButton due to SLDS styling on salesforce classic

Comment: @rmatusiak Editing...

Comment: You are right, it resolves the issue. Maybe one more, small thing. I set timeout to 5000, then to 10000 but it happens immediately actually...

Comment: @rmatusiak Yes, sorry. My original answer was correct. The code should be exactly `oncomplete="setTimeout(location.reload, 5000)"`. Note the missing `()`; we're not calling the function, we're passing a reference to setTimeout for it to call the function in 5 seconds.

Comment: But when I don't put brackets I can see in the console error Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation. The page does not refresh.

Comment: @rmatusiak Hmm. I could have sworn that used to work. Well, okay, you can do this instead: `setTimeout(function() { location.reload() }, 5000)`.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much, I appreciate your help!